# What is the best way to implement data paging with a gridview control in asp.net 4.0 using the Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I'm binding to a Entity Framework list in the code behind file.

I've enabled paging in the gridview control itself.  I've implemented sorting manually using an event associated with GridViewSortEventArgs.

I'm not sure of the best way to implement paging in the code behind.  When I used the .Take() method to limit the results, I get an exception saying the control does not support server side paging.

I have a lot of records, so its critical that I find a way to do this more efficiently than loading all the records.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See this blog post: http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/articles/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-custom-paging.aspx

It builds on the application that this tutorial creates (the link is to the 5th in a series): http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/maximizing-performance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 0):

```
var PagedData = query.Skip((iPageNum - 1) * iPageSize).Take(iPageSize);
```

This is converted via expression parse trees to SQL that is processed on the database. Pretty tight in most cases.